# How to append metadata to a grouped selection by primary key

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I have a list of favorites like:

**Sample Data**

```
| key | item_id | list_name |  customer_id |meta           |
|-----|---------|-----------|--------------|---------------|
| 1   | A-11    | aa11      | 001          | unique-data-1 |
| 2   | A-11    | bb22      | 001          | unique-data-2 |
| 3   | A-26    | cc33      | 001          | unique-data-3 |
| 4   | A-28    | aa11      | 002          | unique-data-4 |
| 5   | J-52    | aa11      | 001          | unique-data-5 |
| 6   | X-53    | aa11      | 001          | unique-data-6 |
```

**Desired Output**

for `@item_id nvarchar(20) = 'A-11'`

```
| key | isFavorited | list_name | meta          |
|-----|-------------|-----------|---------------|
| 1   | Y           | aa11      | unique-data-1 | 
| 2   | Y           | bb22      | unique-data-2 |
| 3   | N           | cc33      | unique-data-3 |
```

And would like to return a selection of all available lists, as well as whether or not a particular item is part of that list, with its meta data.

```
declare @item_id nvarchar(20) = 'A-11'
declare @customer_id nvarchar(20) = 001

select
[key],
[isFavorited] = max(case when [item_id] = @item_id then 'Y' else 'N' end)
[list_name]
[meta]
from favorites
where customer_id = @customer_id
group by [list_name], [key], [meta]
```

**Issues when trying various methods:**

1. The issue I'm having is that since the `meta` is unique the group by destroys the uniqueness of the select
2. A cross apply like the following doesn't apply the correct `meta` based on a matching `key`.

   ```
   cross apply (
     select top 1 
     [meta]
     from favorites
      where customer_id = @customer_id
   )
   ```
3. When selecting by row number, the actual `key` to join back to is lost, so I'm unable to join the `meta`.

   ```
   "noRow" = row_number() over(order by h_po_no asc)
   ```

**I'd like to**

1. Pass in an `item_id` and `customer_id`
2. Return all lists for that customer
3. Get favorite status for each list of passed in `item_id`

   - An item is flagged favorite if it matches both `list_name` and `item_id` for a given `customer_id`
4. Get row primary `key` and `meta` data

How can I return a distinct selection of `list_name`, `isFavorite` status, `key`, and it's `meta`?

Comment: `select top 1 'meta'` is completely different from `select top 1 [meta]`. I suspect that's a simplification and not the actual problem in your query, but even so I'd advise against using quoted identifier syntax with single quotes as opposed to brackets precisely because it's so easily confused with string literal syntax in other contexts.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have corrected the `[meta]` select. I see your point, and prefer the syntax highlighting and readability of the quoted identifier versus `as newColumnName`.

Comment: BTW, the pattern of 'alias' = [expression] is deprecated. You should remove the single quotes around your aliases. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15 Having the alias at the front of the column is fine, but remove the string literal syntax.

Comment: You can still use `[newColumnName] = expression` or (with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`, which is the default) `"newColumName" = expression` if you really prefer. Just don't use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you both for the updates!

Comment: You also have distinct AND group by in the same query. As for aliases, I would remove any quotes entirely. Either use square brackets or use aliases with no weirdo characters and you don't need it at all.

Comment: @SeanLange Syntax updated. Using distinct AND group by returns the correct pared down selection of lists and whether or not the item is a favorite on that list.  Otherwise I get an error `Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function`

Comment: You don't need both distinct AND group by. That returns unique rows with two criteria for determining unique rows. But for the desired output here you don't need distinct or group by. No aggregation is needed.

Comment: @SeanLange Gotcha, I can drop the distinct.

Comment: This question just doesn't make sense. It now seems like you want the first row for each list_name (the order is maybe defined by Key?). That is no big deal. But there is no rhyme or reason why the column isFavorited is populated. The sample query you provided does not return the results you state with the last round of sample data. What is the business rule for isFavorited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Parameters**

```
declare @item_id nvarchar(20) = 'A-11'
declare @customer_id nvarchar(20) = 001
```

**Solution**

```
drop table if exists #tmp

;with cte as (
  select
  [key],
  [list_name],
  [rn] = row_number() over (partition by list_name order by list_name desc)
  from favorites
  where customer_id = @customer_id
  group by [list_name], [key], [meta]
)
select *
into #tmp
from cte
where [rn] = 1

select 
[i],
[json],
#t.[tmp]
from #tmp #t
inner join (
  select
  [isFavorited] = max(case when [item_id] = @item_id then 'Y' else 'N' end)
  [list_name]
  from favorites
  where customer_id = @customer_id
  group by [list_name]
) j 
on j.list_name = #t.list_name
```

Answer (score 1):

To return the desired output you don't need any aggregation at all. A simple case expression and a where clause will accomplish this.

```
declare @Favorites table
(
    MyKey int
    , item_id varchar(10)
    , list_name varchar(10)
    , customer_id varchar(10)
    , meta varchar(20)
)
insert @Favorites values
(1, 'A-1', 'list-1', '001', 'unique-data-1')
, (2, 'A-1', 'list-2', '001', 'unique-data-2')
, (3, 'A-2', 'list-3', '001', 'unique-data-3')
, (4, 'A-2', 'list-1', '002', 'unique-data-1')

select *
from @Favorites

declare @item_id nvarchar(20) = 'A-1'
    , @customer_id nvarchar(20) = '001'

select f.MyKey
    , isFavorited = case when f.item_id = @item_id then 'Y' else 'N' end
    , listName = f.list_name
    , f.meta
from favorites f
where f.customer_id = @customer_id
order by f.MyKey
```

Comment: Without aggregation items are returned that haven't been declared by '@item_id`

Comment: Huh? Using your sample data and the desired output you posted this query returns exactly what you asked for. If there is more complication in the actual data you need to post sample data that represents the issue.

Comment: Should be clearer now, the difference among `item_id`s was too subtle.

Comment: OK so why should 5 and 6 not be returned? And why are 1 and 2 favorited? That doesn't match your description anymore.

Comment: To send less data to the front end and not have to filter the list on the client side. Where can I clear up the description?

Comment: You should update the question with the details here. It is not clear to me why the criteria is now for what rows to return or how to determine if a row is a favorite or not.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have provided an answer if you'd like to take a look. Thank you for the notes on deprecation and style!